# if cell matches any cells in column, auto-populate with value directly to the right of match

Tags: excel

I have a tab with a list of names, directly to the right of their names i have their hourly wage (tab name WAGES)

I then have a tab for each day of the month - If I enter a name in cell A1, I want cell B1 to search Column A in my wages tab (names) and when it finds the matching name, i want it to auto-populate with the wage directly to the right of the name in the wages tab

help!

Comment: What have you tried? This sounds like a `Vlookup()` would work (or `Index/Match`).

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet, hoping for some input on best route to go.

Comment: Check out [Vlookup()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Comment: that worked! thank you so much!